# Increment/decrement button issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

Html markup:

```
<td data-title="Qty" class="vertical_text quantity">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </button>

    <input class="cart-input" type="text" name="qty[]" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $cart['qty']; ?>">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
</td>
```

Script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var quantitiy = 0;
    $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e) {

        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val()); //10

        // If is not undefined

        $('#quantity').val(quantity + 1);

        // Increment

    });

    $('.quantity-left-minus').click(function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());

        // If is not undefined

        // Increment
        if (quantity > 1) {
            $('#quantity').val(quantity - 1);
        }
    });

});
```

I'm using bootstrap and Codeigniter. In my shopping cart table there is two button (-)button and (+)button with input field. if there is is single row in my table and when I'm clicking on the (-) button / (+) button the value of input field increment/decrement properly. but my problem is if there is two or more row in my table if I'm clicking to second row or third row  (-)button/(+)button the value of first row input field increment/decrement. And when I'm refreshing the page the previous value shows up again. Help to increment/decrement button work properly and the value of input field should be update properly. Thank you.

Comment: About the multiple row, did you always use the same id #quantity ? In this case it's normal, jQuery only take the first result with an id (because an idea need to be uniq) .  And about the not refreshed value, if you don't send the value to the server, it's normal ... If I'm correct, I think you need to re-learn some basics in HTML + how work the interaction between client and server